# MSVC preprocessor bug

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to fix a MSVC preprocessor bug that works fine on GCC.

Below is the reduced test case.

```
#define TF_STATUS_MACROS_CONCAT_NAME(x, y) TF_STATUS_MACROS_CONCAT_IMPL(x, y)
#define TF_STATUS_MACROS_CONCAT_IMPL(x, y) x##y

#define TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN(...)                                             \
  TF_STATUS_MACRO_GET_VARIADIC_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL_3, \
                                    TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL_2)              \
  (__VA_ARGS__)

#define TF_STATUS_MACRO_GET_VARIADIC_IMPL(_1, _2, _3, NAME, ...) NAME

#define TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL_2(lhs, rexpr) \
  TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL_3(lhs, rexpr)

#define TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL_3(lhs, rexpr) \
  TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL(                    \
      TF_STATUS_MACROS_CONCAT_NAME(_status_or_value, __COUNTER__), lhs, rexpr)

#define TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL(statusor, lhs, rexpr) \
  auto statusor = (rexpr);                             \
  if (!statusor) {                                     \
    return 0;                                         \
  }                                                    \
  lhs = std::move(statusor)


int foo(int x) { return x * 2; }

int main() {
  int a;
  TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN(a, foo(10));
}
```

For GCC, the preprocessed output is:

```
int foo(int x) { return x * 2; }

int main() {
  int a;
  auto _status_or_value0 = (foo(10)); if (!_status_or_value0) { return 0; } a = std::move(_status_or_value0);
}
```

However, MSVC gives me this:

```
int foo(int x) { return x * 2; }

int main() {
  int a;
  test.cpp(32): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'TF_STATUS_MACRO_GET_VARIADIC_IMPL'
 (a, foo(10));
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What version of GCC and MSVC?

Comment: GCC 7.1.0 and VS 2017 15.5

Comment: `TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN_IMPL_3(lhs, rexpr)` is a function-like macro, but in `TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN(...)` you use it as if it doesn't need arguments?!

Comment: You are passing 4 arguments to `TF_STATUS_MACRO_GET_VARIADIC_IMPL`, but it requires at least 5. "**[cpp.replace]/4** If the *identifier-list* in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis, the number of arguments (including
those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens) in an invocation of a function-like macro shall equal the number of parameters in the macro definition. Otherwise, there shall be **more arguments** in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the ...)." Emphasis mine.